# Property of euclidean norm - proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In my textbook there is lemma:
$(\forall\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^{n})||\vec{x}||=0 \Leftrightarrow \vec{x}=0$ that should be easy to prove. And I have $0\le x_{i}^2\le x_{1}^2+...+x_{n}^2=||\vec{x}||=0$. Which even if it is simple I don't quite understand. I know that right side comes from definition of euclidean norm $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^2}$. For any $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ it is true that $x_{i}^2\le x_{1}^2+...+x_{n}^2=||\vec{x}||$. But how does this prove the lemma? I am still missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing is that (by omitting some of the interior links in you chain of inequalities) you have $$0\le x_i^2 \le 0$$
This means that $x_i^2=0$, and the only way that can be possible is if $x_i=0$. Since this is true for every $i$, you get $\vec x = 0$.

Comment: I see, I couldn't make the last step. thank you